# Userform for displaying the content in spreed sheet

Tags: vba, userform

[image]

Hi Team,

Please help me I am unable to run the following VBA its saying runtime error'1004'

I am trying to display the content in the activesheet in the userform

program:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick() 
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
if Me.ComboBox1.ListCount = 0 Then
For i = 2 To LastRow
Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "a").Value
Next i
End If
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A") = (Me.ComboBox1) Then
Me.txtrfxno = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, “b”).Value
Me.txtsd = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, “c”).Value
End If
Next i
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: I am getting error on 
Me.txtrfxno = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, “b”).Value

Comment: And what's the *text* of the error message?  Those quotes around "b" and "c" look like "smart quotes" - did you paste that directly from the VB editor?

Comment: Run-time error'1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

Yes I just copy-paste the code from VB editor

Comment: Try fixing those quotes and see if that helps: they should be straight like the ones around "A"

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me and its working perfectly - thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line 11:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A") = (Me.ComboBox1) Then
```

It should be:

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
```